# How to find certain text using selectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

I've written a script in python to find the text within `td` tag which is the `next sibling` of first `td`tag using BeautifulSoup in combination with css selectors. If i run the script, i find it working. However, when i do the same using `lxml` library, it no longer works. How can i get my latter script working? Thanks.

This is the content:

```
html_content="""
<tr>
  <td width="25%" valign="top" bgcolor="lightgrey" nowrap="">
      <font face="Arial" size="-1" color="224119">
        <b>Owner Address&nbsp;</b>
      </font>
  </td>
  <td width="75%" valign="top" nowrap="">
      <font face="Arial" size="-1" color="black">
        1698 EIDER DOWN DR<br>SUMMERVILLE&nbsp;SC&nbsp;29483
      </font>
  </td>
</tr>
"""
```

Working one with bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
item = soup.select("td")[0].find_next_sibling().text
print(item)
```

Result:

```
1698 EIDER DOWN DRSUMMERVILLE SC 29483
```

The below script can find the address string:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
root = fromstring(html_content)
item = root.cssselect("td b:contains('Address')")[0].text
print(item)
```

Result:

```
Owner Address
```

It doesn't work when it comes to find the next sibling (applied "+" sign to find the next sibling:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
root = fromstring(html_content)
item = root.cssselect("td b:contains('Owner Address')+td")[0].text
print(item)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\new_line_one.py", line 28, in <module>
    item = root.cssselect("td b:contains('Owner Address')+td")[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i make it work to find the next sibling? Btw, I'm only after css selectors not xpath. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the css3 selector [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators):

> 8.3.1. Adjacent sibling combinator
>
> The adjacent sibling combinator is made of the "plus sign" (U+002B, +)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   immediately precedes the element represented by the second one.

Which means in your selector `td b:contains('Owner Address')+td`, you're asking for a `td` that has the same parent as the `b` which contains 'Address' and is child of another `td`. This node does not exist. To make it work, you need to make sure that you're first partial selector matches the `td`, not the `b` node. Since they contain each other, the following would work:

```
td:contains('Owner Address') + td
```

Note that this `td` has no text (only child nodes), so your snippet from above only prints whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It will work instead `root.cssselect("td:contains('Owner Address') + td")[0].text_content()`.